# Oculus basic Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, oculus

I am trying to create a makefile for compiling an Oculus Rift based program. I have the object files of the Oculus Rift library in a directory and the header files in another directory. Here's my makefile:

```
#####
# MAIN PROGRAM
#####

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = 

DEPS_OVR = ($wildcard LibOVR/Src/*.h) ($wildcard LibOVR/Src/CAPI/*.h) ($wildcard LibOVR/Src/Util/*.h)
DEPS = 

OBJ_OVR = ($wildcard LibOVR/Obj/Linux/Release/x86_64/*.o)
OBJ = main.o 
EXE = BenchOculus

LIBS =

#####
# RULES
#####

all: $(EXE)

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS_OVR) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -Wall -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS) 

$(EXE): $(OBJ) $(OBJ_OVR) 
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(OBJ_OVR) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    chmod +x $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

When I run make, I have the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `(ildcard', needed by `BenchOculus'. Stop.
```

I think the problem may reside in DEPS_OVR and OBJ_OVR but I can't figure how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message, and ask yourself why it's complaining about a target `(ildcard`, when what you wrote was `($wildcard ...`.  That tells you, to within a character or so, where your error is.  Then go back and check the documentation for the `wildcard` function in GNU Make.

Comment: Ok, it's $(wildcard .. and not ($wildcard .., thanks for the hint